# ido-completing-read - How is the history list supposed to behave?

Tags: emacs, elisp, ido

Including the history list makes no difference at all. The colors still appear in the original order.

```
(setq foo '("blue" "green" "red"))
(ido-completing-read "Pick: " '("red" "green" "blue") nil t nil 'foo)
```

What is the function of the history list then? Is there an alternative way to change the order
of elements based on history, like smex?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

History list is used when we press up/down while in minibuffer. It doesn't change the order of elements.